# Writing to a file using a helper class interface, where do I open the ofstream?

Tags: c++, class, file-io

It's kind of a difficult question to put into a single title.  So I'm trying to write the data contained in an Account class out to a file using a member function of a FileIO class.  FileIO is a composite member data object of the Account class. I have 3 Account objects stored in a vector of pointers, which I am looping through to write all of them out to a file.  I'm wondering how I get the WriteData() function to see the open file? I can't open the file within the function itself, because I need all the Account objects to be written out to the file before closing it.

Here's my code:

```
class FileIO
{
private:
    ofstream _accoFile;
public:
    FileIO();
    ~FileIO();
    void WriteData(Account*);
    ofstream& GetoStream();
};

void FileIO::WriteData(Account* acc)
{
    _accoFile << acc->GetAccNum() << "\n" << acc->GetAccOwner()->GetName() << "\n" << acc->GetAccOwner()->GetAddress() << "\n" << acc->GetAccBal() << "\n";
    //acc->WriteAcc(_accoFile);
}

class Account
{
private:
    Person* _accOwner;
    int _accNumber;
    double _accBalance;
    FileIO* _iFile;
public:
    Account();
    ~Account();
    Account(Person*, int, double);
    Person* GetAccOwner();
    int GetAccNum();
    double GetAccBal();
    FileIO* GetiFile();
};
```

In main:

```
FileIO* test = new FileIO();

    test->GetoStream().open("accInfo.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < accountsVec.size(); i++) {
        accountsVec[i]->GetiFile()->WriteData(accountsVec[i]);
    }
    test->GetoStream().close();
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Opening/closing things is exactly what constructors/destructors are for.

Comment: I moved the open/close statements into the constructor and destructor, but that didn't fix it.  My problem is when I open the file that the Account objects should have been written to, only the 3rd objects data is there.  So I think the file is being closed after each WriteData() call, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: From your sample code taken from `main` it doesn't look like the new'ed `test` object is in any way related to the one returned through `GetiFile()` from `accountsVec[i]`. Maybe that's your problem? Provide more context and a solution can be found. Do beware that having each `Account` object have a pointer to a `FileIO` object is a bit of a _wtf_ design.

Answer (score 1):

What makes it difficult to answer your question is that the real issue lies elsewhere:

> FileIO is a composite member data object of the Account class.

For proper [separation of responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), `FileIO` *shouldn't be* a member of `Account`.

Instead, it should be a separate class. With this [SOLID-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design, the problem of opening the ofstream is easily solved, as this could be done e.g. in the constructor:

```
class FileIO
{
private:
    ofstream _accoFile;
public:
    FileIO(const std::string& filename) : _accoFile(filename) {};
    void WriteData(Account*);
};
```

With this design:

- The output file is opened as soon as you create an instance of `FileIO`;
- Several instances of `Account` can be serialized into the same output file;
- The output file is automatically closed as soon as the `FileIO` instance is destroyed.

Below is a simple `main` demonstrating how such a serializer could be used:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Account*> accountsVec;

    FileIO writer("accInfo.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < accountsVec.size(); i++) {
        writer.WriteData(accountsVec[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I understand the assignment demands a common member serializer for all `Account` instances. That's really weird, so it might be worth double-checking. In any case, here is what I could come up with, based on these bizarre requirements.

The serializer could be designed with the typical I/O `open` and `close` methods:

```
class FileIO
{
private:
    ofstream _accoFile;
public:
    void open(const string& filename) { _accoFile.open(filename); }
    void close()                      { _accoFile.close();        }
    void WriteData(Account*);
};
```

Since the serializer is a compound member of `Account`, it should be integrated into the `Account` ctor:

```
Account::Account(Person* accOwner,int accNumber,double accBalance,FileIO* iFile) 
: _accOwner(accOwner), _accNumber(accNumber), _accBalance(accBalance), _iFile(iFile)
{}
```

If `Account` is given the responsibility of saving itself into a target file, it's better to write an `Account` method that implements that responsibility:

```
void Account::WriteData()
{ 
    _iFile->WriteData(this); 
}
```

Below is an example of a `main` based on this design:

```
int main()
{
    FileIO fileio;

    Person person1{"toto","Paris"};
    Person person2{"tutu","London"};
    Person person3{"tata","Lisboa"};

    vector<Account> accountsVec;
    accountsVec.emplace_back( &person1 , 1,   12., &fileio );
    accountsVec.emplace_back( &person2 , 2,  100., &fileio );
    accountsVec.emplace_back( &person3 , 3, 1000., &fileio );

    fileio.open("accInfo.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < accountsVec.size(); i++) {
        accountsVec[i].WriteData();
    }
    fileio.close();    
}
```

Comment: I realize this is a stupid way to do what I'm trying to do, but it's an assignment for school, and one of the requirements is that FileIO be a composite member data object of the Account class. :'(

Comment: @brysonmay15 That's really weird :-/ I've updated my answer based on these requirements.